# align sections side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried several attempts to align the section & main to sit side by side? by using a display of inline-block and floating `<section>` to the left etc. But I am unsuccessful, any help as to what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated :-)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //on mobile - open/close primary navigation clicking/tapping the menu icon
  $('.cd-primary-nav').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-primary-nav')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
  });

  //upload videos if not on mobile
  uploadVideo($('.cd-hero-slider'));

  //change visible slide
  $('.cd-slider-nav li').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedItem = $(this);
    if (!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
      // if it's not already selected
      var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
        activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
      if (activePosition < selectedPosition) {
        nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $('.cd-slider-nav'), selectedPosition);
      } else {
        prevSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $('.cd-slider-nav'), selectedPosition);
      }

      updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
    }
  });

  function nextSlide(container, pagination, n) {
    var visibleSlide = container.find('.selected'),
      navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');

    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
    navigationDot.removeClass('selected')
    pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');

    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
  }

  function prevSlide(container, pagination, n) {
    var visibleSlide = container.find('.selected'),
      navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');

    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
    navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
    pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');

    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
  }

  function uploadVideo(container) {
    container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function() {
      var videoWrapper = $(this);
      if (videoWrapper.is(':visible')) {
        // if visible - we are not on a mobile device 
        var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),
          video = $('<video loop><source src="' + videoUrl + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="' + videoUrl + '.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');
        video.appendTo(videoWrapper);
      }
    });
  }

  function checkVideo(hiddenSlide, container, n) {
    //check if a video outside the viewport is playing - if yes, pause it
    if (hiddenSlide.find('video').length > 0) hiddenSlide.find('video').get(0).pause();

    //check if the select slide contains a video element - if yes, play the video
    if (container.children('li').eq(n).find('video').length > 0) container.children('li').eq(n).find('video').get(0).play();
  }

  function updateNavigationMarker(n) {
    $('.cd-marker').removeClassPrefix('item').addClass('item-' + n);
  }

  $.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    //remove all classes starting with 'prefix'
    this.each(function(i, el) {
      var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
        return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
      });
      el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
  };
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
main {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #2c343b;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

a {
  color: #d44457;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Main Components 

-------------------------------- */


/* -------------------------------- 

Slider

-------------------------------- */

.cd-hero {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.cd-hero-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cd-hero-slider li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.move-left {
  /* slide hidden on the left */
  
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* the is-moving class is assigned to the slide which is moving outside the viewport */
  
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero-slider {
    height: 500px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-hero-slider {
    height: 680px;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Single slide style

-------------------------------- */

.cd-hero-slider li {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cd-hero-slider li:first-of-type {
  background-color: #2c343b;
}

.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #3d4952;
  background-image: url("../assets/tech-1-mobile.jpg");
}

.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #586775;
  background-image: url("../assets/tech-2-mobile.jpg");
}

.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #2c343b;
  background-image: url("../assets/video-replace-mobile.jpg");
}

.cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: #2c343b;
  background-image: url(../assets/img.jpg);
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* this padding is used to align the text */
  
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-img-container {
  /* hide image on mobile device */
  
  display: none;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper {
  /* hide video on mobile device */
  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper video {
  /* you won't see this element in the html, but it will be injected using js */
  
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.cd-hero-slider h2,
.cd-hero-slider p {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0 auto 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.cd-hero-slider h2 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.cd-hero-slider p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.2em 1.4em;
  margin-top: .8em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-btn.secondary {
  background-color: rgba(22, 26, 30, 0.8);
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-btn:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.no-touch .cd-hero-slider .cd-btn:hover {
  background-color: #d44457;
}

.no-touch .cd-hero-slider .cd-btn.secondary:hover {
  background-color: #161a1e;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero-slider li: nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-image: none;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
    left: 5%;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 5%;
    left: auto;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-img-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2,
  .cd-hero-slider p {
    max-width: 520px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-btn {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width, .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    padding-top: 220px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2,
  .cd-hero-slider p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider h2 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Single slide animation

-------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(40px);
    -o-transform: translateX(40px);
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-half-width {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-40px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-40px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-40px);
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-half-width {
    /* this is the visible slide */
    
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .is-moving .cd-half-width {
    /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport 
    wait for the end of the transition on the <li> parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 40px/-40px */
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2),
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
    /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:first-of-type,
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
    /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100px);
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    /* this is the visible slide */
    
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h2,
  .cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width p,
  .cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width .cd-btn {
    /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport 
    wait for the end of the transition on the li parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 100px/-100px */
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected h2 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected p {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  }
  .cd-hero-slider li.selected .cd-btn {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Slider navigation

-------------------------------- */

.cd-slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.cd-slider-nav nav,
.cd-slider-nav ul,
.cd-slider-nav li,
.cd-slider-nav a {
  height: 100%;
}

.cd-slider-nav nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #d44457;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 currentColor;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}

.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(200%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(200%);
  -o-transform: translateX(200%);
  transform: translateX(200%);
}

.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(300%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(300%);
  -o-transform: translateX(300%);
  transform: translateX(300%);
}

.cd-slider-nav .cd-marker.item-5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(400%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(400%);
  -o-transform: translateX(400%);
  transform: translateX(400%);
}

.cd-slider-nav ul::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cd-slider-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}

.cd-slider-nav li.selected a {
  color: #2c343b;
}

.no-touch .cd-slider-nav li.selected a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.cd-slider-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #a8b4be;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-slider-nav a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: url(../assets/cd-icon-navigation.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.no-touch .cd-slider-nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

.cd-slider-nav li:first-of-type a::before {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.cd-slider-nav li.selected:first-of-type a::before {
  background-position: 0 -24px;
}

.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(2) a::before {
  background-position: -24px 0;
}

.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(2) a::before {
  background-position: -24px -24px;
}

.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(3) a::before {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}

.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(3) a::before {
  background-position: -48px -24px;
}

.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(4) a::before {
  background-position: -72px 0;
}

.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(4) a::before {
  background-position: -72px -24px;
}

.cd-slider-nav li:nth-of-type(5) a::before {
  background-position: -96px 0;
}

.cd-slider-nav li.selected:nth-of-type(5) a::before {
  background-position: -96px -24px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-slider-nav {
    height: 80px;
  }
  .cd-slider-nav .cd-marker,
  .cd-slider-nav li {
    width: 95px;
  }
  .cd-slider-nav a {
    padding-top: 48px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .cd-slider-nav a::before {
    top: 18px;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Main content

-------------------------------- */

.cd-main-content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cd-main-content p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #999999;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-main-content {
    padding: 3em 0;
  }
  .cd-main-content p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Javascript disabled

-------------------------------- */

.no-js .cd-hero-slider li {
  display: none;
}

.no-js .cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  display: block;
}

.no-js .cd-slider-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cd-hero">
  <ul class="cd-hero-slider">
    <li class="selected">
      <div class="cd-full-width">
        <a href="" class="cd-btn">Like what I do? Let me know</a>
      </div>
      <!-- .cd-full-width -->

      <div class="cd-bg-video-wrapper" data-video="assets/video/video">
        <!-- video element will be loaded using jQuery -->
        <img src=[!["http://blog.franceandson.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/marilyn-monroe-by-andy-warhol-medium.jpg"][1]][1] alt="" width=1200/>
      </div>
      <!-- .cd-bg-video-wrapper -->
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="cd-full-width">
        <div id="container">
 <div class='module' id='measure'>
            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                <p>Send me a message</p>
                <input class="single" type='text' placeholder='Name' />
                <input class="single" type='text' placeholder='Email' />
                <input class="single" type='text' placeholder='Phone' />
                <textarea class="message" type='text' placeholder='Message'></textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
 <a href="" class="cd-btn">Send</a>
    </div>
      <!-- .cd-half-width -->
    </li>

    <li>
      

     
        <div class="cd-full-width">
        <a href="" class="cd-btn">Thank you</a>
      </div>
      <!-- .cd-full-width -->

      <div class="cd-bg-video-wrapper" data-video="assets/video/video">
        <!-- video element will be loaded using jQuery -->
        <img src=[!["http://www.therealbest.com/img/items/big/587/Turquoise-Marilyn_The-Head-of-Marilyn_789.jpg"][1]][1] alt=""      </div>
      <!-- .cd-half-width -->

    </li>

  </ul>
  <!-- .cd-hero-slider -->

  <div class="cd-slider-nav">
    <nav>
      <span class="cd-marker item-1"></span>

      <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#0">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Tech 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#0">Tech 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
</section>
<!-- .cd-hero -->

<main class="cd-main-content">
  <p>I'd love to hear from you.</p>
</main>
<!-- .cd-main-content -->
```

Comment: what elements are you trying to align and to where?

Comment: section .cd-hero & main .cd-main-content side by side

Answer (score 1):

Here's one quick and simple way:

*In your CSS...*

1. Remove `position: absolute` from `.cd-full-width`.
2. Add `body { display: flex; }`
3. Add `width: 100%` to `.cd-hero`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oos5c05k/1)

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Thank you! this solves the alignment issue however the images I had placed for "intro" & "tech2" now cover & hide the links "like what I do? Let me know" & "Thank You". I believe its an issue with .cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper { top:0;?...

Comment: The images you're referring to weren't displaying from the beginning. I don't recall seeing any in your original code. I just ran the snippet in your question, and it looks just like my answer demo. Which images are you referring to?

Comment: There are 2 image links in both .cd-bg-video-wrapper

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the `src` attribute in those links, you'll see that they use relative, not absolute, URLs. This means the images won't appear outside of your website. Please provide the full web address for the images to appear in the demo.

Comment: 1: http://blog.franceandson.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/marilyn-monroe-by-andy-warhol-medium.jpg 2: http://www.therealbest.com/img/items/big/587/Turquoise-Marilyn_The-Head-of-Marilyn_789.jpg

Comment: Oh, you updated your comment after I posted the revised demo.

Comment: The Demo now shows the issue : the images placed for "intro" & "tech2" cover & hide the  buttons "like what I do? Let me know" & "Thank You" rather than lying behind these buttons...

Comment: add `z-index: -1;` to `.cd-hero-slider .cd-bg-video-wrapper` [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oos5c05k/5/)

Answer (score 0):

For my first suggestion, i would wrap both elements in a container:

```
<div class="hero-main-container">
  <section class="cd-hero">[...]</section>
  <main class="cd-main-content">[...]</main>
</div>
```

and then in your css, add the following:

```
.hero-main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.cd-hero, cd-main-content {
  width: 50%;
}
```

If wrapping them in a container is not an option, positioning them side-by-side would be a second option:

```
//css
.cd-hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}
.cd-main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}
```